# Unable to unzip gz file transferred to HDFS via Flume spool directory

Tags: gzip, hdfs, codec, flume, sink

I am  using spooldir source to move .gz files from SpoolDirectory to HDFS.
I am using following config,

==========================

```
a1.channels = ch-1  
a1.sources = src-1  
a1.sinks = k1  

a1.channels.ch-1.type = memory  
a1.channels.ch-1.capacity = 1000  
a1.channels.ch-1.transactionCapacity = 100  

a1.sources.src-1.type = spooldir  
a1.sources.src-1.channels = ch-1  
a1.sources.src-1.spoolDir = /path_to/flumeSpool  
a1.sources.src-1.deserializer=org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder  
a1.sources.src-1.basenameHeader=true  
a1.sources.src-1.deserializer.maxBlobLength=400000000  

a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs  
a1.sinks.k1.channel = ch-1  
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://{namenode}:8020/path_to_hdfs  

a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true  
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval =100  
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollCount=0  
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollSize=0  
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = CompressedStream  
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.codeC=gzip  
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.callTimeout=120000
```

========================================

So file does get transferred to HDFS but it appends time_in_millis.gz extension at the end.
Also when I try to gunzip the file in HDFS (by copying via terminal) it shows unknown characters in it. So not sure what is going on.

1. I would like to maintain the same filename post transfer to HDFS
2. I would like to be able to unzip the file and read content

Can someone help?

Comment: Hi, Are you able to solve this issue? I am also facing same issue.